# Передача функции в конструктор

Tags: javascript

Имеется конструктор:

```
var Constructor = function (str) {
    this.str = str;
};

Constructor.prototype.someFunc = function () {
    //code
};

var a = new Constructor('hello');
var b = new Constructor('world');
```

Нужно чтобы у `a` и `b` дополнительно были разные методы.
Приходит в голову только передача функции через параметр.

```
var a = new Constructor('hello', func(str, someData){
    //some code
});

var Constructor = function (str, func) {
    this.str = str;
    this.func = func.bind(null, this.str);
};
```

Но как вызвать ее в контексте нового экземпляра объекта, ведь нечто подобное
вызовет ее в контексте конструктора?

Comment: `this.func = func;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Constructor = function (str, func) {
    this.str = str;
    this.func = funс;
};

var a = new Constructor('hello', function() {
    //some code
    console.log(this.str);
});

var b = new Constructor('bye', function() {
    //some code
    console.log(this.str);
});


a.func(); // hello
b.func(); // bye
```

В конструкторе `this` ссылается на экземпляр, поэтому просто присвойте значение, и функция станет методом

Если очень хочется `bind`

```
var Constructor = function (str, func) {
    this.str = str;
    this.func = funс.bind(this); // this опять же ссылка на экземпляр
};
```

Но так, у `a.func` всегда будет контекст экземпляра (`a` в данном случае) и ,передавая потом где-то этот метод как `callback`, контекст теряться уже не будет